# Move an Application Page from WebApplication to Central Administration

Tags: visual-studio, central-administration, application-pages

I've made an Application Page (derived from `LayoutsPageBase`) and it's showing in the WebApplication Settings correctly. Now, I need to move it to the Central Administration level.

1. Must I change my VS2010 SharePoint project Site URL ?
2. If yes, is there another way ?
3. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too complicated.

1. Move your page from the `Layouts` mapped directory to the `TEMPLATE\ADMIN` mapped directory.
2. Modify your Page Link or Module `Elements.xml`

as following :

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction Id="(YourActionId)"
     GroupId="SiteDirectory"
     Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.GeneralApplicationSettings"
     Sequence="1000"
     Title="(YourTitle)">
        <UrlAction Url="_admin/(YourPath)/(YourPage).aspx"/>
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

You can customize the `GroupId` and the `Location` with [these options (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730%28v=office.14%29.aspx). All that left is to go to your Central Administration -> Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Manage Site Collections Features -> Activate your feature.

[image]